# Cannot See My Campaign on Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I visited the Google Analytics Campaign URL Builder web page and created a utm parameter campaign link.  When I visited the "Campaigns" page of my Google Analytics account afterwards, the campaign did not show up.  Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Please explain further the steps you took. Did you visit your website with the URL parameters? Did you take report lag into consideration? Did you check the real-time reporting?

Comment: I did visit the website with the UTM parameters.  The UTM link has existed for a while and there is still no option to view the campaign on my analytics account so I don't know if it's simply report lag.  Can you clarify what you mean by real-time reporting?

Answer (score 1):

There is usually a lag of 24-48 hours from the moment you create a campaign link (and visit it) until it shows up in the GA Dashboard. Just wait a day or two and it should be there.

Since it's been a week since you posted and haven't replied that should have done it.

Comment: No the campaign still hasn't shown up.  Any suggestions?